# Kubernetes cannot access cassandra database

Tags: spring-boot, cassandra, kubernetes

I cannot access my Cassandra database, deployed on the same namespace in kubernetes.

My service has no cluster IP but an internal endpoint cassandra.hosting:9042 but whenever I try to connect from an internal spring application using

```
spring.data.cassandra.contact-points=cassandra.hosting
```

it fails with the error `All host(s) tried for query failed`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How did you configure your endpoint?  Generally, all services and pods in a Kubernetes cluster are discoverable through a standard [DNS notation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/). It looks like this:

```
<service-name>.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local # or
<pod-name>.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local # or
<pod-name>.<subdomain>.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local
```

If you are within the same namespace this would work too:

```
<service-name>
<pod-name>
<pod-name>.<subdomain>
```

I would also check either `core-dns` or `kube-dns` are running and ready:

```
kubectl -n kube-system get pods | grep dns
```

Comment: Can I disable connecting to the given service within the cluster? So just enable it in the same namespace?

Comment: Yes. You can do with `Network Policies`: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/